# Can a 7x7 matrix have 2 real eigenvalues and 5 non-real ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix 7x7 matrix with random numbers (because the numbers in it don't matter).

Can this 7x7 matrix have 2 real eigenvalues and 5 non-real ones?
Or 4 real eigenvalues with 3 non-real ones?

Note the the number of non-real eigenvalue is an odd number and the size of the matrix is also an odd number.

I'm interested in knowing why having an odd number of non-real eigenvalues and an odd number for the size of the matrix affects the solution.

Comment: It can if the matrix is imaginary. If it's a real matrix, your characteristic equation will have real coefficients and thus the complex roots must come in pairs. That is, it's impossible to have exactly 5. If your equation has complex coefficients, it's entirely possible that you have five complex roots and 2 real ones.

Comment: @Viola It's entirely up to you, but I wouldn't put personal information such as the street you live in on your profile.

Comment: @superckl Thanks! Your answer really helped me understand:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a diagonal matrix the eigenvalues are those numbers occurring on the diagonal. Thus any mix of eigenvalues is possible.

However if the matrix is to be real, then no, as the characteristic polynomial must factor into two linear and a 5th degree factor, which then will have to have another real root.